# Android Studio does not see the "android" package from the library file

Tags: android, android-studio

My MainActivity.java file starts like this:

```
package com.example.testble2;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Build;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
```

In the same project, the blessed module is created, with the BluetoothCentralManager.java file, which starts like this:

```
package com.example.blessed;

import android.Manifest;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeScanner;
import android.bluetooth.le.ScanCallback;
import android.bluetooth.le.ScanFilter;
import android.bluetooth.le.ScanResult;
import android.bluetooth.le.ScanSettings;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.os.ParcelUuid;
```

The problem is that in the BluetoothCentralManager.java file all import android.* directives are marked in red with the message "Cannot resolve symbol". Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Try to create the packages one level down on the hierarchy. Such as package com.example.testble2.module1 and com.example.testble2.module2. Tell me the result.

Comment: I created packages one level below - com.example.testble2.module1 and com.example.testble2.module2, but in both all import android.* directives are also marked in red.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the module was created with the command: menu -> new module -> java library, and should be created with the command: menu -> new module -> android library